# Angular 4 how can a directive listen for changes of a property in injected service

Tags: angular, rxjs, directive

i'm building an application using Angular 4, I have a component with the following template:

```
<input
    [value]="myService.myValue"
    >
```

where myService is a service injected into the component:

```
@Injectable()
    export class MyService {

    public myValue: string; // I could use an RxJS observable/Subject here
}
```

I need to add a directive (or something) who is listening for changes of myValue and change the color of the input text.

How can I do it? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a `get` accessor property in the service? That would be really simple and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shared service so when `myValue` changes you listen to it and you apply whatever logic you want.

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    updateMyValue$: Observable<any>;

    private updateMyValueSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.updateMyValue$ = this.updateMyValueSubject.asObservable();
    }

    updateVal(newVal) {
        this.updateMyValueSubject.next(newVal);
    }
}
```

**Component that changes the value:**

```
this.myService.updateVal('new value');
```

**Component that listens to the value's change:**

```
this.myService.updateMyValue$.subscribe(
        (newVal) => {
              this.inputValue = newVal; // I called `inputValue` to the variable that will contain the value of the input. It should be initialized.
              // Here we can apply our own logic such as change color, hide some DOM elements or whatever we need to do
        }
    );
```

**Explanation:**

The first component is sending the new value to the service, in our case `"new value"`.

The second component is subscribed to this `Subject` and as soon as `next()` is triggered it will receieve the new data. In other words, this component is listening to `updateVal()` function and as soon as it's triggered it will receive the data.

It's a very solid and practical way to communicate between components.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngClass or ngStyle as following

```
<input [value]="myService.myValue" 
       [ngStyle]="{'color': myService.myValue === 1 ? 'red' : 'blue'}">
```

or with `ngClass`

```
<input [value]="myService.myValue" 
       [ngClass]="{'color-red': myService.myValue === 1, 'color-blue' : myService.myValue === 2}">
```

Check this plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/2IAxwnXOaWS4TUL7aov0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<input [myDirective]="myService.parameter" myServiceValue="{{myService.value}}" ... >


@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class parameterDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('myDirective') parameter: parameter;
  @Input() myServiceValue: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    switch (this.parameter) {
      case parameter.EnumValue:
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, "my-class", changes.myServiceValue.currentValue > 100);
        break;
      default:
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A subject is way overkill for what you're talking about. In general, are reactive subject should be used sparingly.

You can accomplish what you want with a simple `get` accessor

```
export class MyService {
  myValue_: string;
  get myValue() {
    return this.myValue_;
  }
}
```

If you want the value to flow in the other direction as well you can add a `set` accessor although that would be best avoided since having a view right into your service class would be bit nasty.